# Adding Tooltip to Input causes `findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode` error - Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I would like to add a Tooltip to an Input field. To do this I wrap the input field in the tooltip and it displays as expected. However when I hover over it prints a warning.

**Tooltip/Input**

```
<Tooltip title="Title">
  <Input />
</Tooltip>
```

**Warning**

```
Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Input which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node
span
ClearableLabeledInput@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15995:90
Input@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16374:90
Trigger@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59906:92
Tooltip@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58900:26
./node_modules/antd/es/tooltip/index.js/Tooltip<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20652:62
```

I can hide the error by removing `<React.StrictMode>` but I would like to fix this error.

Is this a bug in Ant Design or am I adding the `Tooltip` incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a problem with Ant Design components. For instance, using the plain DOM `<input>` doesn't cause this error.

Having said that, a workaround is to simply wrap Ant's `<Input>` in a plain DOM element such as `<div>` resolves it:

```
    <Tooltip title="prompt text">
      <div>
        <Input />
      </div>
    </Tooltip>
```

You can see a working example in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-18-2-forked-sis5t?file=/index.js)

Comment: This was it thank you! I'll create an issue for this.

Comment: This answer is such a life saver. No ant design issues got this answer.